# Clojure - difference between quote and syntax quote

Tags: syntax, clojure, quote

```
(def x 1)
user=> '`~x
x
user=> `'~x
(quote 1)
```

Can anyone explain please how it is evaluated step by step?

Comment: You mean  equals `1`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The single-quote operator returns the expression or symbol that you are quoting without evaluating it. The syntax-quote operator returns the expression or symbol that you are quoting (with namespaces added), without evaluating it. The syntax-unquote operator "cancels out" the syntax-quote operator, so to speak, but not the single-quote. You can nest syntax-quotes and syntax-unquotes to perform weird and wonderful feats. My favorite analogy I read for understanding these is to consider syntax-quoting and syntax-unquoting as moving up and down rungs of a ladder ([possible source](https://pragprog.com/book/cjclojure/mastering-clojure-macros)).

In the form `` `x ``, `x` is syntax-quoted, so it isn't evaluated; instead, you get a namespaced symbol (like `user/x`). But in the form `` `~x ``, `x` is syntax-unquoted again, so it is evaluated:

```
user=> `~x
1
```

On to your examples:

**Example 1**

`'` is just sugar for `(quote ...)`.

So `` '`~x `` becomes `` (quote `~x) ``. This in turn becomes `(quote x)` (remember that `` `~ `` doesn't really do anything), which is why the whole expression evaluates to the symbol `x`.

**Example 2**

In `` `'~x ``, let's first replace the `'` with `quote`: `` `(quote ~x) ``. The expression is syntax-quoted, so it won't be evaluated.

So you can think of *the expression* `(quote ~x)` as an "intermediate step." But we're not done. `x` inside the syntax-quote is syntax-unquoted, just as in my example up above. So even though this expression as a whole won't be evaluated, `x` will be, and its value is `1`. In the end, you get the expression: `(quote 1)`.

[Blog post](http://blog.8thlight.com/colin-jones/2012/05/22/quoting-without-confusion.html) on the topic.

Comment: The ladder metaphor @galdre is refer to, is from "Mastering Clojure Macros" https://pragprog.com/book/cjclojure/mastering-clojure-macros

Comment: @Chiron Thanks. I didn't remember where I'd encountered it.